# VisualPHPUnit - Trying to get property of non-object when getting a property of object

Tags: php, phpunit

[VisualPHPUnit](https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit) test.

No, it's not an array.

```
class TestGetChildren extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $objs;
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $objs = array();
        $i=0;
        while ($i<20) {
            $obj = (object) array (
                'ID'=>$i,
                'DIRID'=>0
            );
            if ($i>5) $obj->DIRID = $i-6;
            if ($i>10) $obj->DIRID = 7;
            $objs[] = $obj;
            $i++;
        }
        $this->objs = $objs;
    }

    public function testGetChildren() {
        $objs = $this->objs;
        //var_dump($objs);
        print_r(gettype($objs));
        assert('array' == gettype($objs));
        print_r($objs[19]->ID);
        $vm = new FoldersPermissions($objs);

        //$children =   $vm->getChildren($vm->folders[0]);
        foreach ($vm->folders as $obj) {
            $children = $vm->getChildren($obj);
            print_r($obj->ID."|".count($children)."\n");
            // 0 is a special case, and 1 has 10 children
            if (4 >= $obj->ID && 1 < $obj->ID) {
                //print_r(($children));
                $this->assertTrue(1 == count($children));
            }
            if (7 == $obj->ID){
                $this->assertTrue(count($children) == 9);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Also, output:

```
Debugging Output
19
```

So it actually works. 
What?

Also, apparently $objs is not an array...

*edit* to clarify:
I altered testGetChildren like so:

```
public function testGetChildren() {
    $objs = $this->objs;
    //var_dump($objs);
    print_r(gettype($objs));
    assert('array' == gettype($objs));
```

and got this as a response:

> NULL Warning: assert(): Assertion failed

Comment: From the code you have posted $objs *is* an array. $objs[19] is an element of that array and this seems to be an object of stdClass.

Comment: You'd think that, wouldn't you. Apparently it's a NULL. Curiously, though, the test completes successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I know the reason for the error is because the function testGetChildren has - ignoring case - the same name as the class.

So, probably it interprets the function as the constructor, which messes up the class it inherits.

Answer (score 0):

Liquorvicar is right, $objs is an array, and more - you are just printing the ID of that $objs -arrays 20th object (as array goes from 0 to 19). So it works fine. If you try print_r($objs), that is an array.

Comment: No, no. I'm getting the 'trying to get a property of a non-object' notice specifically from that print_r line.

Comment: Then you are not calling `setup`, isn't that quite obvious? While seeing just a part of the code, its hard to say what you do and what do you dont.

Comment: Ah. It's a test class in VisualPHPUnit. If setup doesn't execute, though --- why am I getting the correct output from print_r? I added the complete test code. Which I probably should have done in the first place.